# Disable checkboxes not working in Internet explorer but works in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable checkboxes in a datatable for few users,  when i open my link through IE, those users can make changes to checkboxes whereas I dont see any issue in Chrome, it works as expected. Users are restricted from checking those boxes.

Below is the code

```
if(getURLParam("filetype"))
    {
        $(".disablePage").addClass('disabledbutton');
        $("#picklistBody").addClass('disabledbutton');
        $("#STATUSDIVID").removeAttr('class').addClass('div-warning').html("This page is view only!");  
    }
```

Can you please let me know how could I restrict users from checking the boxes when they open the Link in IE.

Comment: Which version of IE?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to disable users to not be able to check the checkboxes, use attr or prop to disable them depending on Jquery version:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").prop("disabled", true);
```

This will find all checkboxes on the page and disable them. You may have to modify it slightly if you only want certain checkboxes disabled.

Also I see that you are adding a disabled class for buttons when they are not allowed to be used. This will still allow the user to click the button, though they are styled like they are unclickable. Make sure to disable the button as well:

```
$(".disablePage").addClass('disabledbutton').prop("disabled", true);
$("#picklistBody").addClass('disabledbutton').prop("disabled", true);
```

**Edit: Full code**

```
if(getURLParam("filetype")) {
        // Disable the buttons
        $(".disablePage").addClass('disabledbutton').prop("disabled", true);
        $("#picklistBody").addClass('disabledbutton').prop("disabled", true);

        // Disable all checkboxes
        $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("disabled", true);

        $("#STATUSDIVID").removeAttr('class').addClass('div-warning').html("This page is view only!");  
    }
```

Comment: Enabling/disabling checkboxes works fine in chrome, problem is with the IE browser. I can check the boxes in Internet explorer but I should not do so. how can i stop users from checking off those boxes in IE

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? How are you currently disabling your checkboxes?

Comment: Also what version of Jquery do you have installed?

Comment: Below is my CSS :                                                                                              
 .disabledbutton {
 pointer-events: none; 
 opacity: 0.9;}  , looks like pointer-events doesnt work for checkboxes in IE, is there any other alternate way to disable checkboxes in IE browser?

Comment: So you're only using CSS to disable the check boxes? IE doesn't support a lot of new CSS properties, so use jQuery to disable the check boxes like I put in my answer. If you know that the user doesnt have permission when building the HTML, you could also just include "disabled=disabled" for the checkboxes: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Comment: I've updated my answer to have the full code of what you should try

Comment: Yes, IE dont support pointer-events , but I'm looking if there is any alternative for pointer-events that supports IE? Since my checkboxes are generated dynamically  I cannot do it from the Jquery side taking its ID.

Comment: Yes, you can do this through jQuery. You can run javascript anytime and is dynamic in nature. After adding your check boxes, call the code I posted above. The alternative, and more proper way, of doing what you're asking is to use Javascript. You also dont need the ID's of the checkboxes. The code I posted will search the entire page for checkboxes and disable all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in a comment that you're trying to disable your checkboxes with CSS.

Most versions of IE don't support the `pointer-events` CSS attribute. For a long time it was only supported by Chrome. For a while they were considering deprecating it as well. They also have spotty coverage on mobile.

In other words, don't rely on pointer events; Use HTML `disabled` properties instead.

Comment: Yes, IE dont support pointer-events , but I'm looking if there is any alternative for pointer-events that supports IE? Since my checkboxes are generated dynamically  I cannot do it from the Jquery side taking its ID.

Comment: You can still do it with JQuery on generated HTML. It's the same as how you add classes using jQuery, instead set a `.prop('disabled', true)`